Flutter: How to Automatically Display a Back Button in the AppBar Based on the Nested Navigation Stack?
I'm working on a Flutter app where I'm using GoRouter for navigation with a bottom navigation bar to switch between different sections. Each section has its own nested navigation stack.
I want to automatically display a back button in the AppBar when the user is not on the root route of a section. However, my current implementation is not working as expected. Specifically, the following line does not correctly determine if there is a route to pop in the nested navigation stack:
final canPop = navigatorKey.currentState?.canPop() ?? false;

Here is a simplified version of my code:
app.dart
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/src/authentication/auth_gate.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/views/collection_screen.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/views/conversation_screen.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/views/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/views/new_specimen_screen.dart';
import 'package:hanazono_app/views/scaffold_with_navbar.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _homeNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'home');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _collectionNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'collection');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _newSpecimenNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'newSpecimen');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _conversationNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'conversation');

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  late final GoRouter _router;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _router = GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      initialLocation: '/',
      routes: [
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
              StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
            return ScaffoldWithNavBar(navigationShell: navigationShell);
          },
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: _homeNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/',
                  builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: _collectionNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: '/collection',
                    parentNavigatorKey: _collectionNavigatorKey,
                    builder: (context, state) => const CollectionScreen(),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: 'newSpecimen',
                        builder: (context, state) => const NewSpecimenScreen(),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: _newSpecimenNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/newSpecimen0',
                  builder: (context, state) => const NewSpecimenScreen(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              navigatorKey: _conversationNavigatorKey,
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/conversation',
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    final modelId = state.uri.queryParameters['modelId'] ??
                        'exampleModelId';
                    final modelType =
                        state.uri.queryParameters['modelType'] ?? 'Taxon';
                    return ConversationScreen(
                        modelId: modelId, modelType: modelType);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/auth',
          builder: (context, state) => const AuthGate(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/profile',
          builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

scaffold_with_navbar.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../providers.dart';

class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({
    required this.navigationShell,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key ?? const ValueKey<String>('ScaffoldWithNavBar'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final GoRouter router = GoRouter.of(context);
    final currentLocation = router.routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.fullPath;
    Logger.root.info('Current path: $currentLocation');

    int currentIndex = navigationShell.currentIndex;
    Logger.root.info('Current index: $currentIndex');

    final user = ref.watch(authProvider).maybeWhen(
          data: (user) => user,
          orElse: () => null,
        );

    final navigatorKey = navigationShell.route.branches[currentIndex].navigatorKey;
    final canPop = navigatorKey.currentState?.canPop() ?? false;
    Logger.root.info('Should display back button: $canPop');

    // Log the state of the current tab's navigation stack
    if (navigatorKey.currentState != null) {
      Logger.root.info(
          'Current tab\'s navigation stack: ${navigatorKey.currentState!.widget.toString()}');
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: canPop
            ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  Logger.root.info('Back button pressed');
                  navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
                },
              )
            : null,
        title: const Text('My App'),
        actions: [
          if (user != null && !user.isAnonymous)
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              onPressed: () {
                context.go('/profile');
              },
            )
          else
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.go('/auth');
              },
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_florist),
            label: 'Collection',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: 'New Specimen',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
            label: 'Conversation',
          ),
        ],
        onDestinationSelected: (index) {
          Logger.root.info('Bottom navigation item tapped: $index');
          navigationShell.goBranch(
            index,
            initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Collection Screen
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../providers.dart';

class CollectionScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CollectionScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final currentTabIndex = ref.watch(currentTabProvider);
    final navigatorKey =
        ref.read(navigationShellProvider.notifier).state[currentTabIndex];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the collection screen',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.push('/collection/newSpecimen');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Issue:
When navigating within a tab, the currentLocation only shows the base path of the tab, not the specific nested route (e.g., /collection instead of /collection/newSpecimen). Consequently, the back button logic does not work correctly.
Goal:
Properly manage the nested navigation stack for each tab so that the back button is displayed when not on the root route of the tab.
Question:
How can I correctly check the nested navigation stack for each tab to determine if the back button should be displayed?
Thank you for your help!
